# Acessar a posição do maior valor numa matriz

Tags: python, matriz, revisão-de-código

Bom, sei que já existe um post semelhante (muito semelhante, por sinal) aqui, mas a questão toda é que eu não consigo entender a lógica de programação envolvida. O meu código até então está da seguinte maneira:

```
matriz = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
maior = 0
for linha in range(3):
    for coluna in range(3):
        matriz[linha][coluna] = int(input(f'Digite os valores para [{linha}, {coluna}] '))
    maior = max([valor for linha in matriz for valor in linha])
```

A partir daí, estou simplesmente perdido. Pelas soluções que vi, eu deveria ter feito algo do tipo:

```
    for linha in matriz:
        for valor in linha:
            if posicao[0] < valor:
                x = linha.index(valor)
                y = matriz.index(linha)
                posicao = (y, x)
```

Mas não entendi com clareza o que está sendo feito acima. No caso, por que é "for valor in linha" invés de "for coluna in matriz", ou por que tenho que utilizar o posicao[0]? Me perdoem a ignorância, ainda tô perdido no assunto de matrizes, porque no curso que peguei, não tem uma sessão disso, então tô meio que no "sei lá, só vai".

Answer (score 0):

Uma matriz nada mais é do que uma lista com outras listas dentro, onde cada lista dentro lista maior (vulgo matriz) representa uma linha.

Dessa forma, entenda a matriz como se fosse uma caixa grande com várias caixas pequenas. Para que você tenha acesso ao conteúdo das caixas menores, primeiro você precisa abrir a caixa grande e ir abrindo o que tiver dentro.

O que o código faz é basicamente isso. Em:

```
for linha in matriz:
```

Você está procurando pelas caixas pequenas (leia-se linhas) que estão dentro da  caixa grande (leia-se `matriz`). Com esse `for` você vai acessando cada linha.
Em seguinda vêm o segundo `for`:

```
for valor in linha:
```

Basicamente você pegou uma linha e está acessando os valores de dentro dela. De modo lúdico, imagine que você abriu caixa grande, selecionou uma caixa pequena e o **valor** são os itens que estão dentro dessa caixa.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Essa analogia das caixinhas me ajudou muito. A parte que diz  
```if posicao[0] < valor: ```
Qual sentido de pegar o primeiro elemento da posição e comparar com o elemento da caixa pequena?

Comment: LeandroGuimarães, qual o objetivo final do seu código?

Comment: A ideia é justamente encontrar o maior valor de uma matriz e a sua posição. A parte do código que tem ```if posicao[0] < valor``` pra mim não faz muito sentido. Tô lendo como "Se a primeira posição for menor que o valor...", mas n peguei a lógica.